# google app engine datastore unique id

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On Google App Engine, I would like to create a unique key for a data table. As suggested by [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Kinds_Keys_and_Identifiers), I am trying to do the following:

Suppose I have a model called Message, and the field values are obtained from a web page as follows:

```
message = db.Message()
message.name = self.request.get('name')
message.email = self.request.get('email')
...
message.put()
message.messageId = message.key().id()
message.put()
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct way of creating a unique id (messageId)? I mean: put the entity first, get it's id and assign to messageId, and finally put again? It looks strange.
2. How to prevent the concurrency problem? I know that I can use 'transaction' as follows:

   ```
   @db.transactional
   def storeEntity():
       message.name = self.request.get('name')
       message.email = self.request.get('email')
       ...
       message.put()
       message.messageId = message.key().id()
       message.put()
   ```

But what if this transaction fails? How do I do it until it is successful? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Do you want to create your own unique id, or just use auto-generated id? Because in your code you are setting property messageId with already assigned auto-generated id. You don't need to manually assign it.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Old relational DB concept: there has to be a primary key ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not provide a key, the datastore will return a key for you, so you do not have to put the entity twice. And put will return the key.

So you can :

```
message_key = Message(name = self.request.get('name'), email : self.request.get('email')).put()
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. Uh..., do you have any suggestions about question 2?

Comment: App engine uses optimistic concurrency. You have an option :automatic retries, when a transacrtion fails. See also the docs : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions By the way. It is better to use ndb instead of db and strong consistency using entity groups.

Comment: Is there a concurrency problem when datastore assigns integer id for you and you don't add duplicate data? If you want to get the id upfront before put, allocate_ids is what you want.